# How to get the next Bi-weekly date based on a given start date and today's date in Google Sheets

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, rounding

I am trying to get bi-weekly dates based on a start date that would then provide the next upcoming date following the 14-day sequence from the start date, to get me the date that comes after today's date.

For example, if the start date is `6/15/2022`, I would want the date every 14 days, and using today's date, I want to get the immediate next date that would still follow the 14-day sequence. Using today's date (`6/30/2022`), the next date I should get is `7/13/2022`, which follows the 14-day sequence, since if you do `MOD(DateDif(6/15/2022, 7/13/2022, "D"),14)`, you will get zero.

More Examples

```
Start Date: 6/15/2022
Today's Date: 6/30/2022
Next Needed Date: 7/13/2022

Today's Date: 7/14/2022
Next Needed Date: 7/27/2022
```

I only want to show the single next date, so I do not want to use sequence() or transpose() to fill up multiple rows/columns.

Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=B1+(14*ROUNDUP((TODAY()-B1)/14))
```

[image]